# How to become Professor in England

Tags: economics

I did Master degree in Economics with 60% from India. Now I live in England I want to be professor here but don’t know what to do for it. Can you help me please

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your next step is to earn a doctorate in the field you want to work in. There are more steps after that but it is where you start.

Apply to several universities.